# how to draw this custom shape in flutter?

Tags: flutter

how to draw this custom shape?
Note that this shape is different from a semicircle
I had a problem implementing the following figure in the flutter

tnx

[1]:[this image]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsBcx.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1.Create a svg file for the image

- Using Figma, create a vector for the image shared.
- Export the vector in svg format.

### 2.Get the Path

- You can open the svg file in 2 ways to get its contents:

  i) Open through the browser and go to Inspect element

  ii) Open the file using Notepad or Notepad++
- Below is the content from the svg created in **Step 1**

```
<svg width="474" height="157" viewBox="0 0 474 157" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M45 141L1 156H473L444 149L420 141L398 126L378 106L357 80L334 53L318 35L299 17L270 6L236 1H198L170 11L147 30L124 53L102 80L84 100L65 126L45 141Z" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

- Get hold of the path string from path attribute which is:

```
M45 141L1 156H473L444 149L420 141L398 126L378 106L357 80L334 53L318 35L299 17L270 6L236 1H198L170 11L147 30L124 53L102 80L84 100L65 126L45 141Z
```

### 3.Implement on Flutter

- Create a new dart file with a stateful widget called **CustomPath**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomPath extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomPathState createState() => _CustomPathState();
}

class _CustomPathState extends State<CustomPath> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
    );
  }
}
```

In this class, you'll do only two things:

- Add the `ClipPath` widget
- Create a class within the same file that extends the `CustomClipper` that defines the path of your image and will be added in the `clipper` attribute of the `ClipPath` widget.

### 4.Create the class that extends the CustomClipper

- In my case, I'll name the class as `BezierClipper` with its method `shouldReclip()`.

```
class BezierClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(oldClipper) => false;
}
```

- Then add the getClip() method that is generated using this [link](https://itchylabs.com/tools/path-to-bezier/)  by adding the Path we got in step 2

```
class BezierClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    final double _xScaling = size.width / 414;
    final double _yScaling = size.height / 896;
    path.lineTo(45 * _xScaling, 141 * _yScaling);
    path.cubicTo(
      45 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
      1 * _xScaling,
      156 * _yScaling,
      1 * _xScaling,
      156 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      1 * _xScaling,
      156 * _yScaling,
      473 * _xScaling,
      156 * _yScaling,
      473 * _xScaling,
      156 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      473 * _xScaling,
      156 * _yScaling,
      444 * _xScaling,
      149 * _yScaling,
      444 * _xScaling,
      149 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      444 * _xScaling,
      149 * _yScaling,
      420 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
      420 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      420 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
      398 * _xScaling,
      126 * _yScaling,
      398 * _xScaling,
      126 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      398 * _xScaling,
      126 * _yScaling,
      378 * _xScaling,
      106 * _yScaling,
      378 * _xScaling,
      106 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      378 * _xScaling,
      106 * _yScaling,
      357 * _xScaling,
      80 * _yScaling,
      357 * _xScaling,
      80 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      357 * _xScaling,
      80 * _yScaling,
      334 * _xScaling,
      53 * _yScaling,
      334 * _xScaling,
      53 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      334 * _xScaling,
      53 * _yScaling,
      318 * _xScaling,
      35 * _yScaling,
      318 * _xScaling,
      35 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      318 * _xScaling,
      35 * _yScaling,
      299 * _xScaling,
      17 * _yScaling,
      299 * _xScaling,
      17 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      299 * _xScaling,
      17 * _yScaling,
      270 * _xScaling,
      6 * _yScaling,
      270 * _xScaling,
      6 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      270 * _xScaling,
      6 * _yScaling,
      236 * _xScaling,
      1 * _yScaling,
      236 * _xScaling,
      1 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      236 * _xScaling,
      1 * _yScaling,
      198 * _xScaling,
      1 * _yScaling,
      198 * _xScaling,
      1 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      198 * _xScaling,
      1 * _yScaling,
      170 * _xScaling,
      11 * _yScaling,
      170 * _xScaling,
      11 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      170 * _xScaling,
      11 * _yScaling,
      147 * _xScaling,
      30 * _yScaling,
      147 * _xScaling,
      30 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      147 * _xScaling,
      30 * _yScaling,
      124 * _xScaling,
      53 * _yScaling,
      124 * _xScaling,
      53 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      124 * _xScaling,
      53 * _yScaling,
      102 * _xScaling,
      80 * _yScaling,
      102 * _xScaling,
      80 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      102 * _xScaling,
      80 * _yScaling,
      84 * _xScaling,
      100 * _yScaling,
      84 * _xScaling,
      100 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      84 * _xScaling,
      100 * _yScaling,
      65 * _xScaling,
      126 * _yScaling,
      65 * _xScaling,
      126 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      65 * _xScaling,
      126 * _yScaling,
      45 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
      45 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      45 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
      45 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
      45 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
    );
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(oldClipper) => true;
}
```

### 5.Update the CustomPath class

- Add a ClipPath that will clip the CustomClipper, in this case called `BezierClipper`
- Then add a `Container` as its child which will conform to the new shape.
- Like this:

```
class _CustomPathState extends State<CustomPath> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ClipPath(
          clipper: BezierClipper(),
          child:
              Container(alignment: Alignment.center, color: Colors.black),
        ));
  }
}
```

### 6.Full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomPath extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomPathState createState() => _CustomPathState();
}

class _CustomPathState extends State<CustomPath> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ClipPath(
          clipper: BezierClipper(),
          child:
              Container(alignment: Alignment.center, color: Colors.black),
        ));
  }
}

class BezierClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    final double _xScaling = size.width / 414;
    final double _yScaling = size.height / 896;
    path.lineTo(45 * _xScaling, 141 * _yScaling);
    path.cubicTo(
      45 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
      1 * _xScaling,
      156 * _yScaling,
      1 * _xScaling,
      156 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      1 * _xScaling,
      156 * _yScaling,
      473 * _xScaling,
      156 * _yScaling,
      473 * _xScaling,
      156 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      473 * _xScaling,
      156 * _yScaling,
      444 * _xScaling,
      149 * _yScaling,
      444 * _xScaling,
      149 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      444 * _xScaling,
      149 * _yScaling,
      420 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
      420 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      420 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
      398 * _xScaling,
      126 * _yScaling,
      398 * _xScaling,
      126 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      398 * _xScaling,
      126 * _yScaling,
      378 * _xScaling,
      106 * _yScaling,
      378 * _xScaling,
      106 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      378 * _xScaling,
      106 * _yScaling,
      357 * _xScaling,
      80 * _yScaling,
      357 * _xScaling,
      80 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      357 * _xScaling,
      80 * _yScaling,
      334 * _xScaling,
      53 * _yScaling,
      334 * _xScaling,
      53 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      334 * _xScaling,
      53 * _yScaling,
      318 * _xScaling,
      35 * _yScaling,
      318 * _xScaling,
      35 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      318 * _xScaling,
      35 * _yScaling,
      299 * _xScaling,
      17 * _yScaling,
      299 * _xScaling,
      17 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      299 * _xScaling,
      17 * _yScaling,
      270 * _xScaling,
      6 * _yScaling,
      270 * _xScaling,
      6 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      270 * _xScaling,
      6 * _yScaling,
      236 * _xScaling,
      1 * _yScaling,
      236 * _xScaling,
      1 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      236 * _xScaling,
      1 * _yScaling,
      198 * _xScaling,
      1 * _yScaling,
      198 * _xScaling,
      1 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      198 * _xScaling,
      1 * _yScaling,
      170 * _xScaling,
      11 * _yScaling,
      170 * _xScaling,
      11 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      170 * _xScaling,
      11 * _yScaling,
      147 * _xScaling,
      30 * _yScaling,
      147 * _xScaling,
      30 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      147 * _xScaling,
      30 * _yScaling,
      124 * _xScaling,
      53 * _yScaling,
      124 * _xScaling,
      53 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      124 * _xScaling,
      53 * _yScaling,
      102 * _xScaling,
      80 * _yScaling,
      102 * _xScaling,
      80 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      102 * _xScaling,
      80 * _yScaling,
      84 * _xScaling,
      100 * _yScaling,
      84 * _xScaling,
      100 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      84 * _xScaling,
      100 * _yScaling,
      65 * _xScaling,
      126 * _yScaling,
      65 * _xScaling,
      126 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      65 * _xScaling,
      126 * _yScaling,
      45 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
      45 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      45 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
      45 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
      45 * _xScaling,
      141 * _yScaling,
    );
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a great start. I am not getting the expected size. I am using the BezierClipper in a ClipPath with a photo. The shape came out very short and squashed. I played around with the _xScaling and _yScaling. Setting _yScaling to 400 made it taller but I'm trying to get it perfect. What can I change?

Answer (score 0):

Create a StatelessWidget say MyArc which accepts a diameter.

```
class MyArc extends StatelessWidget {
  final double diameter;

  const MyArc({Key key, this.diameter = 200}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: MyPainter(),
      size: Size(diameter, diameter),
    );
  }
}

// This is the Painter class
class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;
    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCenter(
        center: Offset(size.height / 2, size.width / 2),
        height: size.height,
        width: size.width,
      ),
      math.pi,
      math.pi,
      false,
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Usage:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: MyArc(diameter: 300),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of shape requires Bezier Curves to make.

If you can create this image as an SVG, you can use [this tool](https://itchylabs.com/tools/path-to-bezier/) to create a ClipPath that you can use in Flutter.

Some reading on how to use a ClipPath: https://medium.com/flutterdevs/custom-clipping-in-flutter-8aa0631ef19b